# AEM , Maven : Moving Service from one bundle to another bundle breaks the service wiring

Tags: java, maven, service, osgi, aem

The issue comes when i move a service from one bundle to another new bundle

- I moved one of the service from bundle aem-core-bundle to bundle aem-core-pim-connector.
- And then i refer
  to that **service** in a **servlet** in **aem-core-bundle** using scr
  annotation.
  **@Reference**
- This breaks the wiring of the service and the servlet path in which i am refering to this moved service is not visible to the component anymore.

The only error i see during the build is:

29.12.2015 11:41:53.345 *ERROR* [OsgiInstallerImpl] com.pearson.aem.aem-core-bundle [com.pearson.aem.aemcore.services.content.impl.ContentServicesServiceImpl(1944)] The deactivate method has thrown an exception 
**(java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/ws/rs/client/Client").**

java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/ws/rs/client/Client"

I have already added dependency for **aem-core-pim-connector** in **aem-core-bundle** and both the bundle starts up completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to register the service before using it in another bundle,

please refer the following page
https://hashimkhan.in/aem-adobecq5-code-templates/service/
for reference